# How do I perform a search using mysql REPLACE on sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

How do I perform an SQL query such as this in sequelize?

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE REPLACE(`name`,' ','') LIKE '%$name%'.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sql looks good to me!  :)

Comment: :) I need to know how to use this REPLACE function in sequelize.js.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this out but according to [the documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html#replacements), this should work.

```
sequelize.query('SELECT id FROM table WHERE (`name`,' ','') LIKE :search_name ',
  { replacements: { search_name: '%$name%'  }, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
).then(ids => {
  console.log(ids)
})
```